# Is an Image object without references marked for garbage collection as usual?

Tags: javascript, image, garbage-collection

The documentation for [`Audio()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio#memory_usage_and_management) states that its objects won't be removed from memory by the garbage collection mechanism if the playback is currently underway.

Of course the same cannot be true for [`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) objects as there is no playback.
But since both represent tags, I was wondering if there are specific conditions to the garbage collection of Image objects?

---

Drawing an image on a canvas element might be a real world example for this:

```js
function someFunc(url) {
  let canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  
  // Is this image preserved after the callback was invoked?
  let img = new Image();
  
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }, {once: true});
  
  img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your goal is to minimize your memory impact by ensuring the image can be disposed of once finished?

Comment: @Locke Yeah, memory impact was my concern (especially over longer time periods).